# Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/framework/TestCase

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, junit5, suite

After upgrading from JUnit 4 to JUnit 5 getting this error when i am trying to run test as JUnit in eclipse.
Getting warning: failed to load class 'org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.junit3TestLoader$1'

Comment: You need to do a complete rebuild

Comment: What is the full stack trace and which versions are you using?